# How can I identify "most thread hungry" applications/services on my system?

Tags: linux, cpu, threads, htop

In htop, I see over 1500 threads. How do I know their distribution related to what is running on the machine?

It is remarkable that only 2 are running; so maybe a lot of CPU time is wasted just to visit sleeping threads?

[image]

Comment: Sleeping threads do nothing. They don't get "visited" just to check they're ready to go either. The operating system knows the thread is waiting on *something* to start and it knows what conditions need to be met before it is worth moving the thread onto a CPU to actually do some work. Many threads may well be on a timer to start up, check whether they have a job to do and then shut back down, but that is down to the program and thread itself. "Running" probably has some criteria for how long a thread is "awake" before being counted as running.

Comment: On Windows the Resource Monitor available from Task Manager can tell you number of threads: https://i.stack.imgur.com/3yYBK.png (Don't know about Linux, hence only comments)  For the most part though having a high number of threads is not going to cause any kind of slowdown unless it is astronomically high, like in the hundreds of thousands or more. I have a Win system with 3500 threads and absolutely no issue.

Comment: It seems that there is a default of 32,000 threads *per process* in Linux (https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/maximum-number-threads-can-created-within-process-c/) so having a couple of thousand in an entire Linux system is not likely to be considered anything "bad".

Comment: htop simply counts the number of tasks that it saw having the 'R' (running) state during the last process scan, although I didn't check whether the kernel has any special criteria for reporting 'R' state.

Comment: @user1686 looking into it "RUNNING – This state specifies that the process is either in execution or waiting to get executed." from https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2013/11/linux-process-and-threads/ so basically Running is any thread that is "ready to go". Anything waiting on external inputs, timers or other events wll be "dead" as far as the scheduler is concerned. At a minimum then to be running there has to be active work going on or the thread received it's wake event and is about to start.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Press <kbd>T</kbd> to see threads in a tree view, under their parent processes. You can also add the `NLWP` column showing the number of threads for each process through the <kbd>F2</kbd> htop settings screen. (Despite its name, the column shows you the count of kernel threads and has nothing to do with userspace LWPs.)

[image]

In general, these numbers are nowhere near "unusual" or "excessively large" (even more so for a modern 12-core system). I'd only bother investigating if the total reached 6–7k.

Processes or threads which are not running but only waiting to be woken up by some specific event (e.g. waiting for the poll(2) syscall to return) do not occupy any CPU time. The scheduler [does not keep checking](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/424528/2168) what each task is waiting for and whether needs to be woken up – instead, the event *itself* [knows which tasks to wake up](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/268042/2168) when it completes.

For example, if you have Apache httpd with its 256 threads waiting for incoming connections on a socket, the scheduler doesn't even look at them unless there is activity on the socket.

In other words, the only thing that actually needs to spend CPU time per process or thread is *htop itself* (as it does indeed rescan each task's status every second).